# Get MAX from row with column name (SQL)

Tags: google-bigquery

Sorry if my questin is simple, but I spent one day for googling and still can't figure out how to solve this:

I have table like:

```
userId A B C D E
  1    5 0 2 3 2
  2    3 2 0 7 3
```

And I need each MAX per row with column name:

```
userId MAX
  1     A
  2     D
```

All ideas will be much appreciated! Thanks!
I use Google Big Query so my possibilities are different form MySQL as I understand, but I will try to translate if you have ideas in MySQL way.

Comment: See normalisation. And I note that values can be tied.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `GREATEST`:

```
SELECT userid, CASE GREATEST(A,B,C,D,E)
                    WHEN A THEN 'A'
                    WHEN B THEN 'B'
                    WHEN C THEN 'C'
                    WHEN D THEN 'D'
                    WHEN E THEN 'E'
               END AS MAX
FROM TableName
```

Result:

```
userId  MAX
1       A
2       D
```

Comment: I think someone did that that you linked to MySQL documentation. He is using Google BigQuery, but your solution also work there. I upvoted just to be even here.

Comment: It was really stupid question, thank you! I don't why but I thought that there is no GREATEST in Google Big Query. Thanks again!

Comment: Oh, that was me. I don't believe that this kind of solution does any favours to newbies such as the OP.

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT *, 
  ( SELECT key
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'".*?":[^,}]*')) kv,
    UNNEST([STRUCT(TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') AS key, SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) AS value)])
    WHERE key != 'userId'
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) max_column
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

if to apply to sample data from question as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 userId, 5 A, 0 B, 2 C, 3 D, 2 E UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, 3, 2, 0, 7, 3 UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, 1, 2, NULL, 4, 5
)
SELECT *, 
  ( SELECT key
    FROM UNNEST(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(TO_JSON_STRING(t), r'".*?":[^,}]*')) kv,
    UNNEST([STRUCT(TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') AS key, SAFE_CAST(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)] AS INT64) AS value)])
    WHERE key != 'userId'
    ORDER BY value DESC
    LIMIT 1
  ) max_column
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
```

output is

```
Row     userId  A       B       C       D       E       max_column   
1       1       5       0       2       3       2       A    
2       2       3       2       0       7       3       D    
3       3       1       2       null    4       5       E
```